# How to perform recursive SQL where statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite

**Update**

Thank you to @forpas and @trincot for sharing their solutions and ideas below. I got it working with the following code ([demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8kBRg5jpGcxgWSQf16jTPM/2)):

```
with recursive cte_comments as (
  select 
    *
  from
    comments
  where parent_comment_id = 1
  union all
  select
    this_execution.* 
  from
    cte_comments prev_execution
    inner join comments this_execution
      on this_execution.parent_comment_id = prev_execution.comment_id
) 

select * from cte_comments
```

---

**Original post**

I have the following `comments` table and data in a SQLite database:

**Table structure**

```
-----------------------------------------
| Column            | Type              |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| comment_id        | integer           |
+---------------------------------------+
| parent_comment_id | integer           |
+---------------------------------------+
| comment_text      | text              |
-----------------------------------------
```

**Table data**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| comment_id        | parent_comment_id  | comment_text            |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 1                 |                    | First comment, level 1  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2                 | 1                  | First comment, level 2  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3                 | 2                  | First comment, level 3  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4                 | 2                  | First comment, level 3  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 5                 |                    | Second comment, level 1 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 6                 | 5                  | Second comment, level 2 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 7                 | 6                  | Second comment, level 3 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The data is for nested comment section in a website where `comment_id` is unique and `parent_comment_id` can be `null`. Two or more comments can be under one same `parent_comment_id`. The `comment_text` column contains random strings.

**Question**

How to perform SQL search that will return back all children under a parent comment? For example, when I search for all comments under comment 1, I want comment 2, 3 and 4 (all comments that start with *First comment*) to return back. And when I search for all comments under comment 5, I want comment 6 and 7 (all comments that start with *Second comment*) to return back.

Do I need to have an intermediary/join table? Do I need to alter my table structure? Or, do I need to use another database engine to make it happen?

Comment: Which is your version of sqlite?

Comment: Here is the output for `select sqlite_version();` - 3.15.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a recursive `CTE`:

```
with recursive cte as (
  select * from comments
  where parent_comment_id = 1
  union all
  select t.* 
  from cte c inner join comments t
  on t.parent_comment_id = c.comment_id
) 
select * from cte
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8kBRg5jpGcxgWSQf16jTPM/1).
Results:

```
| comment_id | parent_comment_id | comment_text           |
| ---------- | ----------------- | ---------------------- |
| 2          | 1                 | First comment, level 2 |
| 3          | 2                 | First comment, level 3 |
| 4          | 2                 | First comment, level 3 |
```

Comment: Dont you think OP have asked to pass comment ID as input not the parent_comment_id as 1?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai The question is: *For example, when I search for all comments under comment 1....*

Comment: Exactly, Under comment_id 1 not under parent_comment_id 1.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai So what?

Answer (score 1):

If your version of sqlite is 3.8.4 or greater, then you can use the recursive `with` clause:

```
with recursive cte (id, name, parent_id) as (
  select     comment_id,
             comment_text,
             parent_comment_id 
  from       comments
  where      parent_comment_id = 1
  union all
  select     c.comment_id,
             c.comment_text,
             c.parent_comment_id
  from       comments c
  inner join cte
          on c.parent_comment_id = cte.comment_id
)
select * from cte;
```

In the condition `parent_comment_id = 1` you would mention the id of the comment of which the descendants should be retrieved.

Comment: Thanks. I got `Query Error: Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such column: p.comment_id` error - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8kBRg5jpGcxgWSQf16jTPM/3

Comment: The "p" had to be of course a "c" -- the alias of your table. Corrected.